# How can i create a rails worker which is always connected to an external service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, external, sidekiq, worker

I have a rails application which caches data from external service and also converts it to json. External service uses it's own protocol based on RPC convention.

Basically i need a background worker which keeps a connection alive by pinging back and forth using that protocol. When the rails app sends jobs to it, the worker translates it to queries for an external service and transmits converted json data back to application. Application then caches it and transmits it back to user.

The different approach is to use sidekiq and connect/disconnect on each job. This is inefficient.

I need some advice on this topic. Maybe even a different approach. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a [pool of connections](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#connection-pooling) to be used by the jobs running within Sidekiq.

Comment: Can I answer external server's pings while the connection is not used by sidekiq worker?

Comment: Unlikely.  You need a separate thread with an event loop which handles the connections to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global instance of the connection client, either when the sidekiq process starts or on the first request. I would assume that the client is single threaded which you could deal with by setting the `concurrency` level of Sidekiq to 1. If that is an issue then you will need to do something more complex like creating a pool of connections.

Comment: This can be used. The client is single-threaded. But then how can i answer server's pings? I haven't worked with this low-level stuff yet. Never mind, i better go read the docs.

Comment: You would need to provide more information on the library that you are using and possibly the server

Comment: self coded. You can point me to a doc if there is any, that would be great. I think I'll stick with approach by Mark Perham